# How to use the 'with' function with an array on gamemaker

Tags: arrays, with-statement, game-maker-studio-2

I made a 2d array that stores the id of many different instances but whenever I run a specific number in the array the game just freezes.

This is my code:

```
with global.square_locations[1,1] {

instance_destroy()
}
```

Btw this is what square_locations is equal to

```
global.square_locations ==

[ [ ref 100006,ref 100007,ref 100008,ref 100009,ref 100010,ref 100011,ref 100012,ref 100013 ],
[ ref 100014,ref 100015,ref 100016,ref 100017,ref 100018,ref 100019,ref 100020,ref 100021 ],
[ ref 100022,ref 100023,ref 100024,ref 100025,ref 100026,ref 100027,ref 100028,ref 100029 ],
[ ref 100030,ref 100031,ref 100032,ref 100033,ref 100034,ref 100035,ref 100036,ref 100037 ],
[ ref 100038,ref 100039,ref 100040,ref 100041,ref 100042,ref 100043,ref 100044,ref 100045 ],
[ ref 100046,ref 100047,ref 100048,ref 100049,ref 100050,ref 100051,ref 100052,ref 100053 ],
[ ref 100054,ref 100055,ref 100056,ref 100057,ref 100058,ref 100059,ref 100060,ref 100061 ],
[ ref 100062,ref 100063,ref 100064,ref 100065,ref 100066,ref 100067,ref 100068,ref 100069 ],]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The shown snippet of code is unlikely to be the culprit of the freeze, unless it's something in Destroy/Cleanup events of the object in question.

You can run the game in [debug mode](https://manual.yoyogames.com/#rhsearch=Strings&t=IDE_Tools%2FThe_Debugger.htm) and press Pause/Break button (in debug toolbar) when the game freezes to see what it's stuck at.